# Used mysql to insert data successfully but cannot retrieve the data by select

Tags: java, mysql

I used the JDBC to connect mysql.
This is my table:

```
Table: SensorAttr
Columns:
SID int(11) PK 
TID int(11) 
TMID    int(11) 
SensorType  varchar(45) 
TimeoutType varchar(45)
```

I used `insert` to push my data in `SensorAttr` one by one, and the Driver return integer tells me "Your request is done". However, I can`t find the data in the`Sensor`.

```
PreparedStatement statement = this.con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
int cnt = statement.executeUpdate();

sqlStatement = insert into SensorAttr(SID,TID,TMID,SensorType,TimeoutType) value(33,3,0,'Temp','T1s')
```

The call return 1 to cnt.I mean that **1** mean call has been performed correctly and 1 row affected.

However, in the console, I use select * from SensorAttr . The result show that some rows are missing .

Comment: Sooo, where's your select statement?

Comment: Are you committing your changes? Maybe it's a problem with the default isolation level (`repeatable read`). Try issuing a `commit` in the console before running the select there.

Comment: I have setted autocommit value to 1. I confused that why there are some columns still missing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Here is the thing. The jobqueue is used to get the request and handle it. I use multithreads to send request to JobQueue. Then, JobQueue handle the request in order .Handling the request is just inserting the data to table. SID in table is just request ID in queue. If you insert 48 columns,you will get 38 in the  table. 10 columns are missing. The missing number is unsured.

Comment: I don't get it. How can you "*insert 48 columns*"? Your table only has 5 columns. Are you confusing rows with columns? Or are you saying that you insert the *value* 48 into one of the columns and you *see* the value 38?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry,it is row

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT column1,column2 FROM abc WHERE id=?");
pstmt.setString(1,"101");  
String firstColumn="";
String secondColumn="";
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) { 
     first = rs.getString(1);
     second = rs.getString(2);     
     System.out.println("column1 = " + first +`enter code here`    "column2 = " + second);
} 
rs.close();   
pstmt.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I confused that why can not I see the data even if the callhas been performed correctly

Comment: @Srinivas I think you should format your code before posting or not post it at all. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the execute method() not the update() method if you want to insert items in the table

try,

statement.execute() rather than statement.executeUpdate()

Comment: This is very unhelpful. Either clarify or delete please.

Comment: There are 48 columns to be inserted to the table and 48 times insert.I  can`t find some columns in the table even each insert is success.

Comment: It's not only unhelpful, it's also wrong. `executeUpdate()` **is** the method to execute DML statement.